# MongoDB Upsert Into Array Without Creating Seperate Document?

Tags: mongodb

I have a `purchases` collection with the following schema:

```
   {
      _id: ObjectId(),
      userId: ObjectId(), //reference to Users collection
      items: [
       {
         itemId: ObjectId(), //reference to Items Collection
         purchaseHistory: [
          {
            receiptId: ObjectId(), //reference to Reciepts Collection
            price: number,
            /*other info*/
          }
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
```

I want one document per user and want to add every item purchased by the user, in the `items` array of the respective document. I used the following code for upsertion:

```
db.getCollection("purchases").update({
    "userId": ObjectId("5dd76519fad5b42f3d30b968"),
    "items.itemId": ObjectId("5dd76519fad5b42f3d30b977")
},
    {
        $addToSet: {
            "items.purchaseHistory": {
                price: 153,
                recieptId: ObjectId("5dd76519fad5b42f43565977")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        upsert: true
    }
);
```

It works well for one `itemId`. I'm able to add multiple purchases to `purchaseHistory` array.

But when I run this command with another `itemId`, instead of adding it `items` array, it creates a separate document for it.

**Required Behaviour:**
There should be one document per user and all items (purchased by that user) should append to items array of that document along with its purchase history.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Items inside `purchaseHistory` looks wierd. Is it jsons ? There is a missing `{}`

Comment: @vizsatiz Above mentioned command runs without any error in MongoDB shell. I didn't find any syntax error in it.

Comment: Not the query your schema !

Comment: @vizsatiz thanks, I have corrected it.

Comment: Does the second itemId exist in your db ?

Comment: Yes, it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I, myself found a method to achieve this, but if someone has a better solution please post here.

**What I did:**

Before actual insertion, I ran following command:

```
db.getCollection("purchases").update({
                "userId": ObjectId("user_id_here")
            },
                {
                    "userId": ObjectId("user_id_here"),
                    $addToSet: {
                        "items": {
                            "itemId": ObjectId("item_id_here"),
                            "purchaseHistory": []
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    upsert: true
                });
```

After running this above command, I used the following command for insertion:

```
db.getCollection("purchases").update({
    "userId": ObjectId("user_id_here"),
    "items.itemId": ObjectId("item_id_here")
},
    {
        $addToSet: {
            "items.$.purchaseHistory": {
                price: 153,
                recieptId: ObjectId("reciept_id_here")
            }
        }
    }
);
```